# I'm trying to import a javascript module, but for some reason the console is unable to find it in the same directory

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

this is my code for the server in node.js

```
/*server.js*/
    var http = require("http");
    var fs = require("fs");
    var js=require('/.sample.js'); /*console says that js is undefined*/
    function send404Response(response){
        response.writeHead(404, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
        response.write("Error 404 - Page not found");
        response.end();
    }


   function onRequest(request, response) {

    if( request.method == 'GET' && request.url == '/' ){
        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
        //Open file as readable stream, pipe stream to response object
        fs.createReadStream("./sample.html").pipe(response);
    }else{
        send404Response(response);
    }

}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
console.log("Server is now running...");
```

the console says that js is undefined and takes me to module.js document
which is as follows

```
 var filename = Module._findPath(request, paths, isMain);
  if (!filename) {
    var err = new Error("Cannot find module '" + request + "'");
    err.code = 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND';
    throw err;
  }
  return filename;
};
```

and this is the code for javascript related to my web page
    /*sample.js*/

```
 var toggler=function()
{
    if(document.getElementById("wrapper").className=='')
    {   
        document.getElementById("wrapper").className+="menuDisplayed",
        document.getElementById("toggler").className="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-left"
        document.getElementById("button").style["transform"]="translate(145px,0)";
        document.getElementById("page-content").style["transform"]="translate(150px,0)";
    }
    else
    {   
        document.getElementById("wrapper").className='';
        document.getElementById("toggler").className="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right";
        document.getElementById("button").style["transform"]="translate(0,0)";
        document.getElementById("page-content").style["transform"]="translate(0,0)";
    }
},
var addition= function(a)
{   
    var field;
    var z=document.getElementById("secondary1");
    document.getElementById("header").innerHTML="";
    document.getElementById("header").innerHTML+=a.innerHTML;
    var y=document.getElementById("secondary");
    var checker=document.getElementsByName("message")[0];
    if(checker!=null)
        {
            var parent=document.getElementById("first");
            var child=document.getElementsByName("message")[0];
            parent.removeChild(child);
        }
    if(a.innerHTML.substr(4)=="Contact")
    {
        document.getElementById("i1").style.visibility="visible";
        document.getElementById("l2").style.visibility="visible";
        document.getElementById("div2").style.visibility="visible";
        document.getElementById("l3").style.visibility="visible";
        document.getElementById("div3").style.visibility="visible";
        document.getElementById("l2").style.zIndex="0";
        document.getElementById("l3").style.zIndex="0";
        document.getElementById("div2").style.zIndex="0";
        document.getElementById("div3").style.zIndex="0";
        document.getElementById("icon").style.visibility="visible";
        document.getElementById("calendar").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("l1").innerHTML="Name";
        field=document.getElementsByName("date")[0];
        field.id="i1";
        document.getElementById('i1').setAttribute("placeholder","Name");         
        document.getElementById("l2").innerHTML="Number";
        document.getElementsByName('i2')[0].placeholder="";
        document.getElementsByName('i2')[0].type="tel";

        document.getElementById("l3").innerHTML="Email";
        document.getElementsByName('i3')[0].placeholder="E-mail";
        document.getElementsByName('i3')[0].type="email";

    }
    if(a.innerHTML.substr(4)=="Note")
        {
            document.getElementById("calendar").style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementById("l1").innerHTML="Note";
            var p=document.createElement("textarea");
            document.getElementsByClassName("input-group")[0].appendChild(p);
            p.name="message";
            p.setAttribute("rows","8");
            p.setAttribute("onfocus","liner()");
            document.getElementById("l1").htmlFor="message";
            document.getElementById("i1").style.visibility="hidden";
            document.getElementById("l2").style.visibility="hidden";
            document.getElementById("div2").style.visibility="hidden";
            document.getElementById("l3").style.visibility="hidden";
            document.getElementById("div3").style.visibility="hidden";
            document.getElementById("l2").style.zIndex="-2";
            document.getElementById("l3").style.zIndex="-2";
            document.getElementById("div2").style.zIndex="-2";
            document.getElementById("div3").style.zIndex="-2";
            document.getElementById("icon").style.visibility="hidden";
        }
    if(a.innerHTML.substr(4)=="Appointment")
        {
        field=document.getElementsByName("date")[0];
        field.id="date";
        document.getElementById("date").style.visibility="visible";
        document.getElementById("l2").style.visibility="visible";
        document.getElementById("div2").style.visibility="visible";
        document.getElementById("l3").style.visibility="visible";
        document.getElementById("div3").style.visibility="visible";
        document.getElementById("l2").style.zIndex="0";
        document.getElementById("l3").style.zIndex="0";
        document.getElementById("div2").style.zIndex="0";
        document.getElementById("div3").style.zIndex="0";
        document.getElementById("icon").style.visibility="visible";
        document.getElementById("calendar").style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById("calendar").style.visibility = "visible";

        document.getElementById("l1").innerHTML="Date";

        document.getElementsByName("date")[0].placeholder="DD/MM/YY";

        document.getElementById("l2").innerHTML="Place";
        document.getElementsByName('i2')[0].placeholder="Place";
        document.getElementsByName('i2')[0].type="text";

        document.getElementById("l3").innerHTML="Agenda";
        document.getElementsByName('i3')[0].placeholder="Agenda";
        document.getElementsByName('i3')[0].type="text";

        }
        document.getElementById("form1").reset();
}
module.exports={
    toggler,
    addition
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You just made a mistake with relative path,
you should write

`var js=require('./sample.js');`

The dot for relative path must be before slash. You can read more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)), for example.

Dot means current directory and the slash is a directory separator or root directory if it came at the start of the string.

Comment: exports.runInThisContext = function(code, options) {
  var script = new Script(code, options);
  return script.runInThisContext(options);
};

Comment: Without error message I can't say exact, but I think issue is that you are trying to run browser javascript in context of node.js.

Answer (score 0):

**remove , after toggler function**, it should work, it is because of improper syntax, even my break point has shown up at that point when I had a semi colon at unnecessary place.